# Automatic open new browser tab on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, firefox, safari, applescript, automator

Im trying to create a action in Automator, but I am not sure if its possible only use this software or I would need use applescript.

I need to create a action for when I set a specific URL in some tab on my browser (preferred Firefox but could be Safari) it automatic open a new url in a new tab.

Someone knows if its possible? And how can I do it?

Comment: You want to enter a URL in address bar of a browser after which it should open that URL in new tab ?

Comment: No, should open other specific URL in a new tab.

Comment: i.e. a method/automation that opens a new tab with **YOUR_URL.COM** when you enter **SOME_URL.COM** in address bar ?

Answer (score 1):

This should work. It’s an AppleScript.

```
set YourURL to "www.google.com"
set URLtoOpenOn to "https://au.yahoo.com/?p=us"

repeat
    tell application "Safari"
        set URLs to URL of every document
    end tell

    repeat with theItem in URLs
        if theItem = URLtoOpenOn then
            tell application "Safari" to open YourURL
        end if

    end repeat
    delay 3
end repeat
```